# How to implement checkbx with custom listview

Tags: android

I want to make product list with their price,name,image and checkbox,
User checks the product as the user wants and then pass it to second activity,
       
 In second activity it display the item checked with their price,So what method i have to use specially for **checkbox**  input,I am newbie to android so please help me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a class Product with price, name ...

You have to create a layout (list_row.xml) with the format that you want, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_title_list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_list"
    android:longClickable="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_title_list"
    android:longClickable="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_title_list"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_title_list"
    android:id="@+id/img_sync"
    android:longClickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After that, you need a List Adapter, the best way is create a Custom List adapter

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>
{
private  List<Product> objects;
private Context context;

public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Product> objects) 
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Incidence getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    if(objects.get(position)==null) return -1;
    return objects.get(position).getId(); // your database id

}

   @Override
public void addAll(Collection<? extends Product> objects) {
    this.objects= new ArrayList<>(objects);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}




@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    Incidence rowItem = getItem(position);  // get selected item

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }

    /* Access to row components  */

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_list); // name
    TextView subtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle_list); // price
    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_sync); // image


    title.setText(rowItem.getName());
    subtitle.setText(rowItem.getPrice());
    img.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share);  


    return convertView;
}

}
```

In your fragment or activity  you create the adapter:

```
public class FragListIncidences extends ListFragment
{


    public void initUI() // include this in your onCreate
    {
        mAdapter = new  ProductListAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<Product>());

        setListAdapter(mAdapter); // because of ListFragment
    }
}
```

The checkbox functionality that you want can be implemented in two ways:

- Add Cechbox component in your list_row.xml
- You can use a contextual action mode menu. Here you have an example  http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

  ```
  public void initUI() // include this in your onCreate
  {
      mAdapter = new  ProductListAdapter(getActivity(),
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<Product>());

      setListAdapter(mAdapter); // because of ListFragment
     mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

      mListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new  AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()
      {

          @Override
          public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                                long id, boolean checked) {
              // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
              // such as update the title in the CAB

              final int checkedCount = mListView.getCheckedItemCount();
              mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");

          }

          @Override
          public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
              // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB


                  switch (item.getItemId()) {

                      case R.id.action_get:
                          getSelectedItems();
                          mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                          return true;

                      default:
                          return false;
                  }

              return false;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
              // Inflate the menu for the CAB
              MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
              contextual_menu =menu;
              inflater.inflate(R.menu.subactions, menu);


          }

          @Override
          public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
              // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
              // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.


          }

          @Override
          public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
              // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
              // an invalidate() request
               return false;
     }
   });
   }


   private void getSelectedItems()  {
        final SparseBooleanArray selected = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();


        for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
           if (selected.valueAt(i))
                doWhateverYouWant (selected.keyAt(i));
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In java you have to instantiate each checkBox that you put into your layouts (i.e. `CheckBox checkbox1 = new (Checkbox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);`
Then all you have to do is put a few `if()` statements into your onCreate like this:

```
if(checkbox1.isChecked == true){
//send the info to your next activity
}else{
//nothing
}
```